# What is the meaning of cofactor expansion?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I understand how to perform a cofactor expansion in finding the determinant.  Can you explain what this method is really capturing or what thinking leads us to use this method?

Comment: I suppose the first question is *how has the determinant been defined* for you so far?  One of the common definitions is using signs and permutations.  Other people have it defined *as* the result after using laplacian expansion.  See [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48748/how-to-prove-the-cofactor-formula-for-determinants-using-a-different-definition) and the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Proof).

Comment: Hi @JMoravitz really appreciate the links. At this point I feel more familiar with the Laplace expansion definition and while the definition never called this out specifically, the formula looks similar.